# How to use current logged in user as PK for Django DetailView?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

When defining URL patterns, I am supposed to use a regular expression to acquire a PK from the URL.

What if I want a URL that has no PK, and if it's not provided, it will use the currently logged in user? Examples:

- visiting `/user` will get a DetailView of the currently logged in user
- `/user/edit` will show an UpdateView for the currently logged in user

I tried hard-coding the `pk=` in the `Detail.as_view()` call but it reports invalid keyword.

How do I specify that in the URL conf?

My sample code that shows PK required error when visiting `/user` URL:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'user/$', 
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=Account,
            template_name='user/detail.html')),
)`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative approach would be overriding the `get_object` method of the `DetailView` subclass, something along the line of:

```
class CurrentUserDetailView(UserDetailView):
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Much cleaner, simpler and  more in the spirit of the class-based views than the mixin approach.

EDIT: To clarify, I believe that two different URL patterns (i.e. one with a `pk` and the other without) should be defined separately in the urlconf. Therefore they could be served by two different views as well, especially as this makes the code cleaner. In this case the urlconf might look something like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/$", UserDetailView.as_view(), name="user_detail"),
    url(r"^users/current/$", CurrentUserDetailView.as_view(), name="current_user_detail"),
    url(r"^users/$", UserListView.as_view(), name="user_list"),
)
```

And I've updated my example above to note that it inherits the `UserDetailView`, which makes it even cleaner, and makes it clear what it really is: a special case of the parent view.

Comment: Just a comment, since you seem to be comparing your approach to mine: subclass the view directly is **simpler**, but less **reusable**. A mixin can be reused, mixed (doh) with multiples views, sharing the same base behavior :3

Comment: Absolutely. I wasn't comparing them in the sense that one is superior to the other, I just meant that each has a use case that it fits better.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't define that on the URL definition, since you don't have access to that information.

However, what you *can* do is create your own mixin and use it to build views that behave like you want.

Your mixin would look something like this:

```
class CurrentUserMixin(object):
    model = Account

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            obj = super(CurrentUserMixin, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        except AttributeError:
            # SingleObjectMixin throws an AttributeError when no pk or slug
            # is present on the url. In those cases, we use the current user
            obj = self.request.user.account

        return obj
```

and then, make your custom views:

```
class UserDetailView(CurrentUserMixin, DetailView):
    pass

class UserUpdateView(CurrentUserMixin, UpdateView):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic views uses always `RequestContext`. And [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#users) paragraph in the Django Documentation says that when using RequestContext with auth app, the template gets passed an `user` variable that represents current user logged in. So, go ahead, and feel free to reference user in your templates.

Comment: Thanks for this but I wasn't referring to templates. I wanted to get it done outside templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the details of the current user from the [request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user). If you'd like to see a different user's details, you can pass the url as parameter. The url would be encoded like:

```
url(r'user/(?P<user_id>.*)$', 'views.user_details', name='user-details'),
```

`views.user_details` 2nd parameter would be `user_id` which is a string (you can change the regex in the url to restrict integer values, but the parameter would still of type string). [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups)'s a list of other examples for url patterns from the Django documentation.